# SKSpriteNode will not fadeInWithDuration using SKAction in sequence Sprite Kit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

Im running 3 SKActions in a sequence, the 1st two run just fine but the fadeInWithDuration does not fade in the node, the node just gets added right away when the view loads. Do I have to set the the initial alpha channel for the node to 0? Can someone help with problem?

```
- (void)setUpButtonStart
{
    SKSpriteNode *buttonStart = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"start"];
    buttonStart.name = @"buttonStart";
    buttonStart.position = CGPointMake(900,50);
    [self addChild:buttonStart];

    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.5];
    SKAction *readIntro = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"intro.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
    SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:1.0];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, readIntro, fadeIn]];

    [buttonStart runAction: sequence];
}
```

Comment: I would give that a try, set alpha to 0 before running the fade action.

Answer (score 18):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeInWithDuration%3a), the `fadeInWithDuration` action changes the `alpha` property of the node from its *current value* to 1.0 (100% opacity).

That's why you're not seeing the fade-in - your action will not actually do anything, since the default alpha value of a node is 1.0, it will go from 100% to 100%.

As Steffen has suggested in his comment, all you need to do is set `buttonStart.alpha = 0.0` before the action is executed.

Comment: This is the best answer, I think you can accept it as a best answer ;)

Comment: Yes that works great, thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: What if you don't want to fade all the way to alpha = 1?  What if you only want to fade until alpha = .8?

Comment: @user1639164 you don't use fadeInWithDuration in that case, but instead you go with [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:.8 duration:(NSTimeInterval)]